# Qt - Q_OBJECT vs. #include <QObject>

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

Does using `Q_Object` macro and `#include <QObject>` have the same effect? In other words, are they two different ways for the *same* purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

No. You need `Q_OBJECT` in the class definition of things you want signals/slots on, *in addition* to having the right headers included.

From the [`QObject` api docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) :

> **Notice that the Q_OBJECT macro is
>   mandatory for any object that
>   implements signals, slots or
>   properties.** You also need to run the
>   Meta Object Compiler on the source
>   file. We strongly recommend the use of
>   this macro in all subclasses of
>   QObject regardless of whether or not
>   they actually use signals, slots and
>   properties, since failure to do so may
>   lead certain functions to exhibit
>   strange behavior.

Just look at the various examples in the Qt documentation for more details and sample code. The [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) reference is a good place to look. Also look at the [Object Model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/object.html) reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain this in more detail if possible? `You need Q_OBJECT in the class definition of things you want signals/slots on`? Thanks

Comment: Please read the documentation for Q_Object that Mat linked. There is even a sample class listed within that document, that shows how the Q_OBJECT macro is used.

Answer (score 3):

They are used for two different purposes.

[Q_OBJECT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT):

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other services provided by Qt's meta-object system.

If you want to use signals,slots and other meta-object features, you need to have the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

`#include<QObject>`:

This is used to include qobject.h header file, so that you can use the functions available in the class `QObject`.. Say for eg., `QObject::connect()`.

And to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro you have to `#include <QObject>`.

Answer (score 0):

No. You add this macro to classes derived from `QObject`. But you still need the headers as Mat says! See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT